# Place colored balls in boxes that makes it hard to pick few boxes that contains large proportion of each color

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

There are $n$ boxes filled with red, blue and yellow balls. A box can be empty and it can also contain more than one color. For example, a box can have three red balls, ten blue balls and one yellow ball in it.

Joe comes in and can choose $k$ out of the $n$ boxes. Joe calculates the following: for each color he calculates the ratio of the balls that he has inside the $k$ chosen boxes and the number of balls of the same color in all of the $n$ boxes. For example, if there are ten yellow balls in the $k$ chosen boxes and ninety yellow balls in the $n$ boxes altogether, then Joe would get $\frac{1}{9}$ ratio for the yellow balls.

Let's call these ratios $\lambda_r$, $\lambda_b$ and $\lambda_y$ for the red, blue and yellow balls, respectively. Joe's final score is the minimum of these three ratios. Joe wants to maximize his score.

Now we have a chance to place the balls inside the boxes in any way we want. Our goal is to make Joe's life hard and place the balls in a way that Joe's final score is the lowest when he chooses the $k$ boxes in an optimal way. Is is true that it is enough for us to place exactly one ball in each of the boxes?

---

Background

Original problem: There are 10 boxes and only red and blue balls are placed in them. Prove that you can always select 4 boxes such that you have at least one third of the red and one third of the blue balls in the 4 boxes.

After solving it, we (I was working on it with others) proved that if there are $$ boxes, you can choose $$ out of them, and let further assume that $−1|−1$ (note that the original problem satisfies this condition), then the best ratio that you can garantee to have from both of the colors is $\frac{k-1}{n-1}$.

For general $n$ and $k$ we have found only a recursive formula for the best ratio, but was able to prove that it is enough to check the cases when there is only one ball in each of the boxes.

Now when we have 3 colors then the corresponding result is: if $k-2|n-2$, then the best ratio we can garantee is $\frac{k-2}{n-2}$. But we don't know what happens in general. This is what we want to figure out.

Comment: So $k$ and $n$ are fixed in advance, and then we place the balls? And there is no limit to the number of balls we can use?

Comment: That's all correct.

Comment: What are the values of the ratios for empty boxes ? It has to be defined. Should it be $1$ or $\infty$, or $0$ ?

Comment: @JohannesTrost: as long as at least one ball of every color is placed somewhere among the $n$ boxes (which ought to be a requirement, of course), it seems like the ratios are clearly defined. E.g., if Joe's $k$ boxes contain no red balls, then his $\lambda_r=0$.

Comment: @JohannesTrost: you are right, thank you for pointing it out. I would choose 1 since in that case 100% of the corresponding color of balls would be in Joe's chosen boxes. But in the non-interesting special case when k = 0, I would prefer to define this ratio as 0.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I saw the following problem somewhere - there are 10 boxes and only red and blue balls are placed in them. Prove that you can always select 4 boxes such you have at least one third of the red and one third of the blue balls in the 4 boxes.

After solving it, we (I was working on it with others) proved that if there are $n$ boxes, you can choose $k$ out of them, and let further assume that $k-1|n-1$ (note that the original problem satisfies this condition), then the best ratio that you can garantee to have from both of the colors is $\frac{k-1}{n-1}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: For general $n$ and $k$ we found only a recursive formula for the best ratio, but was able to prove that it is enough to check the cases when there are only one ball in each of the boxes.

Now when we have 3 colors then the corresponding result is: if $k-2|n-2$, then the best ratio we can garantee is $\frac{k-2}{n-2}$. But we don't know what happens in general. So this is the motivation behind my question.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for the suggestion. I wrote the background after the question.

Comment: This type of problem sounds very familiar. I would recommend looking up "scheduling problems" and "waiter problems" as keywords, though neither fits exactly as far as I can recall right now.